# JQuery Carousel Continous slide on mouse Over

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on Jquery carousel, I have a functionality that it slides images on mouse over but its sliding only once, I have to apply functionality that it continously starts sliding images on mouse over and on mouse out it stops sliding. 
I have used interval and calling mouseover event after 1.5 mins,but I am having two problems with it 1st Its Hanging the Browser 2nd Even on mouse out its still sliding(I have tried clearing interval on mouseout but not worked)
Below is my code of carousel

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#carousel_ul_3 li:first').before($('#carousel_ul_3 li:last'));
            $('#right_scroll_3 img').mouseover(function () {   
                //get the width of the items ( i like making the jquery part dynamic, so if you change the width in the css you won't have o change it here too ) '
                var item_width = $('#carousel_ul_3 li').outerWidth() + 10;

                //calculae the new left indent of the unordered list
                var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul_3').css('left')) - item_width;
                //make the sliding effect using jquery's anumate function '            
                $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, 500, function () {

                    //get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made) '
                    $('#carousel_ul_3 li:last').after($('#carousel_ul_3 li:first'));

                    //and get the left indent to the default -210px
                    $('#carousel_ul_3').css({ 'left': '-210px' });

                });
                window.setInterval(event_3, 1500); //Setting Interval


            });

            $('#right_scroll_3 img').mouseout(function () {
               clearInterval
            });

            //when user clicks the image for sliding left
            $('#left_scroll_3 img').mouseover(function () {

                var item_width = $('#carousel_ul_3 li').outerWidth() + 10;

                /* same as for sliding right except that it's current left indent + the item width (for the sliding right it's - item_width) */
                var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul_3').css('left')) + item_width;

                $('#carousel_ul_3:not(:animated)').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, 500, function () {

                    /* when sliding to left we are moving the last item before the first list item */
                    $('#carousel_ul_3 li:first').before($('#carousel_ul_3 li:last'));

                    /* and again, when we make that change we are setting the left indent of our unordered list to the default -210px */
                    $('#carousel_ul_3').css({ 'left': '-210px' });
                });
                window.setInterval(event_3, 1500);//Setting Interval

            });
});




 function event_3() {
            $("#right_scroll_3 img").mouseover();
            $('#left_scroll_3 img').mouseover();
        }
```

How can I continously slides carousel on mouse over and stop it on mouseleave?